# Sitecore upgrade to latest version

Tags: upgrade

I am totally new in migration in Sitecore. Currently, I am using Sitecore 9.1.1 and we would like to upgrade it on Sitecore 10.2. I have followed the link :

```
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/102/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_102.aspx
```

I have few queries related to document as well as on SXA:

- In the document there is one step related to install a new version of instance(Sitecore 10.2). My question is how can we get our old website data in new version of instance(Sitecore 10.2) if we install it from installation guide.
- How can we upgrade modules such as Sitecron and powershell etc? Is there any documentation related to them?

Kindly guide me here.

Answer (score 1):

Since Sitecore 10.1.0, upgrade strategy has changed. You can refer the introduction section in the upgrade document.

1. Create a copy of all the databases from 9.1.1 and run scripts mentioned in the document. (Caution: Some scripts may take hours to complete. In case if you do not want the 9.1.1 xDB data (if enabled currently) and if you can start fresh in 10.2.0, then some time consuming tasks can be avoided. )
2. Install the new version of Sitecore 10.2.0 instance separately.
3. Attach the copied and upgraded databases to the new Sitecore 10.2.0 installation. (now your content is copied to Sitecore 10.2)
4. Deploy your custom solution on top of the new installation.
5. Perform some post-upgrade steps.
6. Install the custom modules which you have in your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution-1:**
You can use Sitecore Razl tool to get your old website data into your new version Sitecore instance, you can read more about this by reading below links:

https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Razl
https://www.layeronemedia.com/en/Resources/Blog/Dazzlingly-Easy-Sitecore-Content-Comparison-with-Razl

**Solution-2:**
You can run database upgrade script mentioned in upgrade guide.

For upgrading your powershell just go to Sitecore 10.2 installation page url and you will see powershell module as well under Modules section you can download it from there and install it into Sitecore Instance.

Powershell compatibility version table with Sitecore versions  table can be checked from below url:
https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix

Comment: Are you certain there are database upgrade scripts that take you from a SQL based Sitecore 9.x into an IAR based 10.x?