# Upgrading the Sitecore version

Tags: sitecore-client, upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade from Sitecore version 9.0.2 to 10.3.0 directly or do we first need to upgrade to any intermediate version

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can directly upgrade from Sitecore 9.0.2 to 10.3.0. As per the upgrade document, If you are upgrading from Sitecore XP 8.1.0 or later you can upgrade directly to
Sitecore XP 10.3.0. However, if your solution is based on an earlier version of
Sitecore, you must first upgrade to Sitecore XP 8.1.0 before you can upgrade to
Sitecore XP 10.3.0. Here is the link to upgrade to your Sitecore version.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/installation-and-upgrade-guides/index.html

Hope this will help.

Comment: Is there any proper guide or Sitecore documentation which can be followed for the upgrade

Comment: @TestUser The link I have shared to you is an official Sitecore document for upgrade

Comment: @TestUser Here some useful links that you can refer. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30736/sitecore-upgrade-to-latest-version